# selecting using nth child selector jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to make a selection in jquery using nth child selector I have the index number as a variable suggestions;
but  `$('.search_filter:nth-child('+suggestions+')').focus();`
does not focus the 2 element if `suggestions=1`
so please tell me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

The [`nth-child-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)  uses a `1` based index to get the sibling at the given index. So if you want the second sibling, you'd use `2`.

If they are not all siblings, or you just want a `0` based index, use the [`eq-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) instead..

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of the `nth-child` selector is that, when it's used with a class, it only applies to an element if it is the nth element *and* has the class. Without seeing any of your code, my guess is you're actually trying to target the nth occurrence of an element with the class "search_filter."